# How to align vertical text in a table?

Tags: html, css, dom

I am trying to render a table that contains vertical text in its headers at the top.  As Gecko doesn't yet support `writing-mode:vertical-rl`, I am trying to do this using `transform:rotate(90deg)`.  I have gotten some way to doing this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4r3qeway/

However, the text is vertically centered in the table header cells, whereas I want the text to be vertically aligned at the bottom.  Is there any way I can do this?  Note that I can't hard-code the heights of the cells because the header cell text will change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
table td {
    background-color: yellow;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;

}
```

Just added `vertical-align:text-bottom;`

[image]

Comment: Wow, can't believe I was so close to getting it working!  Thanks.